# Sed command to save pattern to a new file

Tags: linux, sed

I have a question:
Write a Linux sed command to save lines that match the pattern “number” (upper or lowercase) for the file: datat.txt and save results (overwriting previous contents) to: ~/results.txt

I use this command:

```
sed -n -i '/number/p' data.txt>~/results.txt
```

But when I use more command to look at results.txt file, it showed the empty text file. PLease let me know did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you use two options

- `-n` : quiet mode, no output
- `-i` : in place edit

so you overide original file, keeping only pattern, and outputing nothing.

maybe you intend ?

```
sed -n '/number/Ip' data.txt > ~/results.txt
```

- without `-n` flag, all line will be echoed
- `I` flag for case insensivity

---

man sed

> -n, --quiet, --silent
>
> suppress automatic printing of pattern space

> -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
> edit  files in place (makes backup if extension supplied).  The default operation mode is to break symbolic and hard links.  This can be changed with --follow-symlinks and
> --copy.

Comment: I was going to save lines which contain the pattern 'number', overwrite the original file and save the final result to a new file name results.txt

Comment: -i : isn't it for ignoring upper/lowercase?

Comment: -i ignore case for `grep`, not `sed`.

Comment: oh, I see. Thank you so much

Comment: Thanks everyone. It works!!! Have a great day ^^